# Conditionally create resources with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I’m trying to write a module to deploy Sensu on AWS, the plan was to use elasticache for Redis but now I’m facing an edge case. Some of our VPCs have tenancy set to dedicated and we can’t use elasticache there(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AmazonVPC.EC.html), I thought I could work around this by conditionally using elasticache or deploying a redis cluster in a ASG. I’ve written the code and used:

```
count = "${replace(replace(var.vpc_instance_tenancy,"/.*dedicated.*/","0"),"/(.*default.*|^$)/","1")}"
```

to decide if I should create the elasticahe cluster or the ASG, the problem is that I need to pass a hostname or IP address to the Sensu servers and api nodes so that they can connect to Redis, was planning to use:

```
redis_host = "${coalesce(aws_elasticache_cluster.redis_cluster.cache_nodes.0.address,aws_elb.redis_lb.dns_name)}"
```

but this always fails because one of the resources never gets created and I can’t reference it in the `coalesce` function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, looks like we can reference inexistent resources if we use the splat variable format, like this:

```
redis_host = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.redis_cluster.*.cache_nodes.0.address, aws_elb.redis_lb.*.dns_name), 0)}"
redis_port = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.redis_cluster.*.cache_nodes.0.port, list(var.redis_port)), 0)}"
```

so the nonexistent resource will return an empty list and the other one will return a single element list, I concat them both together and get the first element.